# How to get inputs from keyboard using dialog view in the Pepper emulator ? (Android Studio)

Tags: python, docker, nao-robot, pepper

I'm using android studio and I need to emulate a conversation with Pepper emulator by using its dialog view. I'm using the following code to connect to pepper emulator and to talk with him:

```
import qi
import argparse
import sys
import time
import os



def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--pip", type=str, default=os.environ['PEPPER_IP'],
                    help="Robot IP address.  On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--pport", type=int, default=9559,
                    help="Naoqi port number")
    parser.add_argument("--sentence", type=str, default="hello",
                    help="Sentence to say")
    parser.add_argument("--language", type=str, default="English",
                    help="language")
    parser.add_argument("--speed", type=int, default=100,
                    help="speed")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    pip = args.pip
    pport = args.pport
    strsay = args.sentence
    language = args.language
    speed = args.speed

    #Starting application
    try:
       connection_url = "tcp://" + pip + ":" + str(pport)
       app = qi.Application(["Say", "--qi-url=" + connection_url ])
    except RuntimeError:
       print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + pip + "\" on port " + str(pport) +".\n"
           "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
       sys.exit(1)

     app.start()
     session = app.session

     tts_service = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")

     tts_service.setLanguage(language)
     tts_service.setVolume(1.0)
     tts_service.setParameter("speed", speed)
     tts_service.say(strsay)
     print "  -- Say: "+strsay

     tts_service.say("what's your name?")
     print " --Say: "+ "what's your name?"


     person = raw_input('name: ') #get input from the keyboard using terminal, but I need to take input from dialog view of pepper emulator

     tts_service.say("Hi: "+person)
     print " --Say: "+ "Hi "+ person

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

In the code there is `tts_service.say("Hi: "+person)` that it is used to show the conversation on the dialog view. Is there something similar to get information form the dialog view? In the conversation I used the function `raw_input` but this takes input from the terminal and not from the dialog view.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from NAOqi 2.9, the dialogues are to be written using the `Chat` and `QiChatbot` APIs. They are connected with the dialog view, so you will be able to use it to emulate speech input.

Check out [this tutorial](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/tuto/qichatbot_tutorial.html#qichatbot-tutorial) on how to write a simple dialogue in an Android-based application, instead of Python. There is a sample project you can clone to try it out directly.